# Why does Magento overwrite my keywords

Tags: magento, keyword, meta-tags

I have a weird problem.
Within a template `(phtml)` I set Keywords via

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head)->setKeywords('bla, bla, bla');
```

In an other `.phtml` from another block, which is rendered afterwards, I still have the keywords (`checked in debugging with ... ->getKeywords()`).

But, when the page is fully rendered, the keywords are set to the default ones. I just debugged through the whole process until `renderLayout()` is finished, but I can't find the line, where the keywords are set to default..

Does someone know any workaround ?

Comment: You say "a template". Are the keywords being set after the head is rendered? Try putting a breakpoint in `template/page/html/head.phtml` to see when it is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing a closing quote around 'head'.  Should be:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setKeywords('bla, bla, bla');
```

Comment: After half day of searching this question/answer saved my day. Will upvote as soon as I can.